# How to style the Views pager with Twitter Bootstrap 'pagination' class

Tags: 7, views, paging

I have

```
    <div class="item-list">
       <ul class="pager"><li class="pager-current first">1</li>
          <li class="pager-item"><a href="#">2</a></li>
...

       </ul>
     </div>
```

I would like to style it using bootstrap

```
    <div class="item-list pagination">
       <ul><li><a href'#'>1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
...

       </ul>
     </div>
```

How do I alter the output using

```
MYTHEME_pager(&variables) {

return theme_pager($variables);
}
```

?
Here is the content of $variables.

[image]

EDITED
So far I can somehow alter it by copying from views.inc the function function theme_views_mini_pager($vars), but I encounter the following blockers:

- there is no similar theme function for full pager
- there is no way to change the wrapper class item-list or to add pagination class aside.

Here below is the return of theme_views_mini_pager($vars)

```
return theme('item_list',
  array(
    'items' => $items,
    'title' => NULL,
    'type' => 'div',
    'attributes' => array('class' => array('pagination')),
  )
);
```